# How to read specific rows in excel file in R

Tags: r

I have an excel file `.xlsx` from which I want to read `BE71:CZ71` and `BE76:CZ76` and want to append these as columns to a pre-existing data frame. I could not find any argument equivalent to startRow such as "startColumn" in read.xlsx.
I was hoping to use something like `read.xlsx(<file_name>,startRow=3, startColumn="BE"..)` but there is nothing such as startColumn.
How do I pick up a row starting from a particular column and put it in a vector or a list which I can transpose to "cbind" to a data frame?
An example in which an excel file has 10 rows and 10 columns and something is read from the 5th row from the 4th column onwards would work for me to understand how to do the original problem. Thank you.

Comment: `read_excel()` from the `readxl` package has a range argument

Comment: if you want to transpose your data use `t()` or `purrr::transpose()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(readxl)

df1 <- read_excel(path, range = "BE71:CZ71")
df2 <- read_excel(path, range = "BE76:CZ76")

df_final <- cbind(as.data.frame(df1,df2,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your example problem (a 10x10 matrix initialized at the top left of the excel sheet):

```
library(readxl)
excel_example <- read_excel("~/Desktop/excel_example.xlsx")
fifthrow_fourthcolumn_onwards <- as.matrix(excel_example[5:10, 4:10])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(openxlsx)  
a<-read.xlsx("<filename>",startRow=3,colNames=TRUE)
p<-as.data.frame(t(a[c(69,74),-c(1:56,105:263)]),row.names = FALSE)
```

`-c(1:56.105:263)` drops columns up to `BD`(56), and from `DA`(105) through to the last populated column in the sheet. `c(69,74)` chooses rows 71 and 76 relative to `startRow=3`.